# Bifurcations associated with a continuous dynamical system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Let us consider the system

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -a \frac{xy}{1+x} - x + y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= -bx + cxy - d\frac{xy}{1+x} + ey
\end{align*}

$(0,0)$ is one of the fixed-point of the above system. I have calculated the Jacobian matrix at $(0,0)$.

I was wondering if the above system can exhibit Hopf bifurcation?

I tried to proceed analytically using the Hurwitz criterion mentioned in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation)
for the vdP oscillator.

Applying the method, I am getting the following condition for Hopf bifurcation $0<b<1$ and $e=1$. Is this correct? can this be visualized?

**EDIT:**

Is there any test/ method to check for the Hopf bifurcation in many parameter systems such as this one?

Comment: The necessary condition for Hopf bifurcation would be ${\rm tr}\, J = 0, \; {\rm det}\, J > 0$, where $J$ is Jacobi matrix at $(0, 0)$ and ${\rm tr}\, J = 0$ and $ {\rm det}\, J > 0$ are its trace and determinant. Since at Hopf bifurcation you have $\pm i \omega$ as eigenvalues, it's easy to see why these conditions are necessary for bifurcation.

Comment: Thank you! $Tr J =0$ matches with one of the conditions in Hurwitz criteria! but I am thinking about $det J >0$ ?can we discuss a bit more in [Dynamical systems chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)?

Comment: $c_{0,1}<0$ in Hurwitz criterion contradicts with $det  J >0$? is this correct?

Comment: I know only about Routh-Hurwitz criterion which allows to determine whether a polynomial has roots with ${\rm Re}\, \lambda < 0$ only. I don't know which version of criterion do you use.